# Protect/restrict content provider in android

Tags: android, security, android-contentprovider

I have a context provider in my application.

AFAIK, content provider data can be shared between applications.

How I can I make sure that content provider data is only readable and writable by me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:exported="false"` to the [`<provider>` element in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported).